# Small CSS image not displayed correctly

Tags: css

I'm having a problem displaying a small image using CSS. I'm trying to show an icon sized picture (the picture has a few pixel border so it isn't edge to edge) but the image itself isn't centered when it's displayed and part of it is being hidden by the right and bottom shadows of the surrounding box. I like the look of the shadows but I think the image is so small, the shadows of the box can't be ignored in the sizing. Here's my CSS. Any ideas?

```
.delete_button {
    background: url('trash_can.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 24px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of the trash can image?

Comment: The overall image is 20px x 24px. This includes a border around the image so the image itself wouldn't go all the way to the edge. The answer below works great. I just had to adjust the numbers a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, adjusting the background-position values until your image is positioned correctly:

```
.delete_button {
    background: url('trash_can.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 24px;
    display: inline;
    background-position     : -3px -4px;
}
```

Expanding on this a little further, you might want to try to add all your small images into one icon image in a matrix style. Then you can select just the image you want using the width, height and background-position. This will allow all your icons to be loaded at once as a single file, reducing internet traffic. When a "new" icon is needed, it will already be cached and immediately be available.

```
background-image: url("icons.png");
background-position: 30px 40px; /* Use these values to select your small image contained in your large image */
background-repeat   : repeat;
width           : 20px;     /* or however large your icon is */
height          : 24px;     /* or however large your icon is */
```

Comment: The background-position numbers work great. Thanks. I like the idea of putting all the icons into one file. I'll have to try that later.